# Detect Scroll event while already on top (Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to fire up an action when the user is already on the very top and want to scroll further up.

I managed to do it using the wheel event for normal computers but that won't work with phones.  Is there a way to track that?

[js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9ww4601/4/)

```js
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.foo').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0 && document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0) {
      console.log('OBOVE THE TOP')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">

</div>
```

Comment: I think you'll find what you are searching for with the [Touch Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mousewheel you could use scrollTop to detect the viewports position on the page.

Best of luck with it!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <style>
        body{
            height: 5000px;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi!
        <script>
        jQuery(window).on('scroll' , function(){
            var height = $(this).scrollTop();
            if(height < 0){
                console.log('ABOVE THE TOP');
            }
            if(height > 0){
                console.log('Below THE TOP');
            }
            if(height == 0){
                console.log('At the top');
            }
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The thing about that is that the first if will never fire because scrolltop will never go above the document top. In fact the scroll event wont even fire if u are already on the top. 

here is your code: 

https://jsfiddle.net/65ot28p4/

Comment: Okay... So why not use jQuery-mobile and trigger the code you already have on mobile. https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/triggering-a-wheel-event-on-mobile/